# Must I specify the parent activity name in the Android Manifest?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, android-navigation

I have an activity that starts another activity.
Is it mandatory that I specify the parent activity in the Android Manifest?
Im asking this because there might be other activities that will start this one as well, so should I specify all of them?

```
android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As per  [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#parent) -> section `android:parentActivityName`:

> The system reads this attribute to determine which activity should be started when the user presses the Up button in the action bar. The system can also use this information to synthesize a back stack of activities with `TaskStackBuilder`.

So you only need to specify that if you're going to use up-navigation (as opposed to navigation by back button) or [TaskStackBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/TaskStackBuilder#addParentStack(android.content.ComponentName)). In other cases, you don't need it.

For more information, see the [up-navigation docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20190402172312/https://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/ancestral-temporal). (Archived from the [original](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html), which now redirects to the [Jetpack Navigation docs on designing navigation graphs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-design-graph))

Answer (score 14):

While it should be defined if upward navigation or backstack synthesis is desired, note that the attribute `android:parentActivityName` was introduced in API Level 16.

For prior releases, parent activity information is accessed from attributes defined inside of a `<meta-data>` tag that is declared inside of the child `<activity>` tag.

Example:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".DetailActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity"/>
    </activity>
```

Inside of the `<meta-data>` tag, set the `android:name` attribute to `android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY`, and the `android:value` attribute to the parent activity class name (i.e. the same class name as that assigned to `android:parentActivityName`).

Unless API level is known, both the `<meta-data>` and inline specifications are recommended.

For more on specifying the parent activity, see: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#SpecifyParent

In addition, consider defining the `android:launchMode` attribute inside of your main `<activity>` tag to set the desired behavior of upward navigation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Answer (score 8):

You don't necessarily need to define the `parentActivity` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. You can use the below code for the back navigation enabled:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
```

And implement this:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    if (itemId == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

But if you define the `parentActivity` in the manifest, then the system reads this attribute to determine which activity should be started when the user presses the Up button in the action bar. i.e, it will create a new instance of the `parentAcivity`, means it will call the `onCreate()` of the parent activity.

Comment: As you  say, the manifest method creates a new instance, so does the onOptionsItemSelected not do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify every Activity in the manifest which you call via Intent or Launchers, that the system can find it. So, mark one Activity as the Launcher that your App can get started and register every other Activity, which you call in your App.

If you have a BaseActivity like this:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity{}

public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity{}
```

than you only have to register MyActivity, because BaseActivity is not called by the system but you.

Comment: What if BaseActivity and MyActivity have different parent activity?

Answer (score 0):

No its not necessary to specify parent activity in `manifest` like this

```
android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
```

for `navigationUp` you can also use `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` and `onSupportNavigateUp()` method [Take a Look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686555/display-back-button-on-action-bar/37185334#37185334)