# Fragment and BindingFragmentActivity is not assignable to 'android.app.Activity' after upgrading to API 28/Android X

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-manifest, androidx

I'm upgrading my old project to use latest android apis, gradle build, etc... and I'm running into this issue with my Android Manifest.

I have a few activities set like below:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.company.name.ui.ColorPickerActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_photo_library"
         android:parentActivityName="com.compant.name.ui.CaptureMenuFragment"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.company.name.ui.CaptureMenuFragment" />
        </activity>
```

Where I get a error that says:

```
Fragment  is not assignable to 'android.app.Activity'
```

In reference to the android:parentActivityName above. What should it be instead? It was working in previous target api setting.

I looked through some SO posts and they mention changing Fragment to FragmentActivity but that causes other build issues like I can't use "`getActivity()`" method in my intent instance.

E.g: `Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SearchProductActivity.class);`

Is there a better solution to this?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Even with regards with BindingFragmentActivity, in my manifest it says:

```
com.company.name.ui.ColorActivity' is not assignable to 'android.app.Activity'
```

After I upgrade to API 28 and Android X. What is wrong with this code in my manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.company.name.ui.ColorActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_color"
            android:parentActivityName="com.company.name.ui.ColorsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.company.name.ui.ColorsActivity" />
        </activity>
```

Comment: Try removing `android:parentActivityName` and it's metadata if you do not have `Up button in the action bar` functionality. Read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207762/must-i-specify-the-parent-activity-name-in-the-android-manifest)

Comment: @nimi0112 I did remove the parentActivityName and metadata but it still complains

Comment: Oh for the activity above in the edit, it extends: BindingFragmentActivity. What's the equivalent for Android X/Api 28. I think that's the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to declare your fragment in the `Android Manifest` file. A fragment is a `reusable UI component` which can be attached to any activity.

A fragment takes the properties related to `Screen Orientation`, `Theme` etc from its parent Activity.

Regarding your question to change `fragment` to `FragmentActivity`, you can still access use the methods which are in `FragmentActivity`.

E.g: for getting the context `getActivity()` can be replaced with `FragmentActivityName.this`.

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477997/difference-between-activity-and-fragmentactivity).

Hope this helps.
Thank you.

Comment: So then should I just get rid of the parentActivity that declares the fragment from above and only leave activity?

Comment: @Euridice01 Yes, Only activities should be declared in the Manifest file.

Comment: @Euridice01 Hey did this solution solved your problem?

Comment: I'm still having activity issues in my manifest. I will update my post