# parentActivityName is not working as expected

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

I have 3 activities in sequence.
Order Details Screen -> Images List Screen-> Image View Screen

For Order Details, I didn't provide parentActivityName

For Images List Screen, I provided

android:parentActivityName=".activities.OrderDetails"

For Images View Screen, I provided

android:parentActivityName=".activities.OrderDetails"

But when i click back button while in Image View screen, it is still taking me to the previous activity only (Images List) which is in the Activity stack generally.
Whereas I was expecting it to come back to OrderDetails Screen because I mentioned android:parentActivityName=".activities.OrderDetails".

I would like to know why it is overriding the parentActivityName, and how to make it work as expected.

Comment: Finish the Images List Screen activity after opening Image View Screen activity.

Comment: then what is the use of "parentActivityName" ? I expected it to override the activity stack approach and take user to the activity defined in parentActivityName.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19207786/8738231