# How do I show back button in Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I tried this code to show my `ProfileActivity`:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_profile) {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Contracts.this, Profile.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

When I click on Profile menu Item I can see my `ProfileActivity` but I not have any back button on my `ActionBar` to return in my previous activity.

So, how can I show some back button? Is correct my code to display an activity from my menu?

Comment: possible duplicate of [display back button on action bar - android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686555/display-back-button-on-action-bar-android)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At your Profile Activity check if there's something missing:

```
public class Profile extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // etc...
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.action_profile:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

The function `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)` requires you to define the parent activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
    <activity android:name="com.example.ServicesViewActivity" >
            <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.ParentActivity" />
    </activity>
```

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back

Comment: Not work:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mybusiness.myapp/com.mybusiness.myapp.Profile}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference

Comment: The problem is pretty simple- your activity is inheriting from the new `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity`. We should be using a call to `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`.

Answer (score 5):

In `onCreate()` method of `Profile.class` put this,

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and this,

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem)
{       
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Not work:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mybusiness.myapp/com.mybusiness.myapp.Profile}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference

Comment: For completeness I would add the `finish()` call in the `onOptionsItemSelected` to illustrate how you can go back to the previous activity.