# How to go back by using action bar in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have to get this as a result:

[image: Screenshot]

Moreover, how do I add colour in the action bar's background?

Comment: [Please check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686555/display-back-button-on-action-bar) this has been addressed here already

Comment: Now use ToolBar instead of Actionbar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Create toolbar.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="50dp"
  android:background="@color/orange"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.Theme"/>
```

**Include this toolbar in your activitys xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/app_bg"
  android:orientation="vertical"/>


<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**create your activity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

protected ActionBar actionBar;
protected Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_profile);
     toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
     setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
             finish(); //here add your back function code.
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Click [here](http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/actions.html) to add back action button in your actionbar and add onClick methocd for that button.
For adding background to your actionbar refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us).

Hope this helps.