# Error on doing a background task after returning from child task

Tags: java, android, android-savedstate

I'm not sure I fully understand what needs to be done to retrieve data after returning from a child activity. I don't need to pass data to the parent activity. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-android-activity-state/151940#151940) for reference, they do mention onPause and onResume as well as possible solutions but should I use saved preferences instead of onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState? It fails at the background task of checking the boolean. I also used this [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) for further assistance.

Code Below:

```
@Override 
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
    // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
    // killed and restarted.
    savedInstanceState.putString("type",type);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
    // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    type = savedInstanceState.getString("type");
}

public class getFeed extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> contentFeed = new ParseQuery<>("UserCommentary");
        if(type.equals("object1")){
            //Query for object1
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if(type.equals("object2")){
        //Query for object2
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    commentary.setAdapter(vCommentDetailAdapter);
    vCommentDetailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

EDIT: Added more info to code

Comment: When do you execute your AsyncTask?

Comment: That is executed on the onCreate method

Comment: have you check that `type` value isn't null?

Comment: it wouldn't need to be null if the values are being saved and returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In hindsight of your comment that the `getFeed` AsyncTask is getting executed in `onCreate()`.

You are basically calling it too earlier. See [here](http://staticfree.info/~steve/complete_android_fragment_lifecycle.svg) for the Android Activity lifecycle.

`onCreate()` / `onStart()` gets called before `onRestoreInstanceState()`. So put the execution of the Task in your `onResume()` method.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that it needs to be called each time from `onResume`?

Comment: @RGM-79FPGMStriker Yup, you can not change the android lifecycle. But if you want to call it from `onCreate` you can store the type value in the `SharedPreferences`

Comment: it is possible to just call the `onRestoreInstanceState` from the on create?

Comment: @RGM-79FPGMStriker No, see the link that I provided in the answer.

Comment: So how would that look like ?

Answer (score 0):

I found that this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24767296/2471892) accomplishes what I needed, without the necessity saving the data & reloading data.