# How to intercept the fragment call to popBackStack() in MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

In my Application, i'm transitioning to a `DetailsFragment` when the user clicks on a list item. and there are TWO options to be back at the main `Fragment` (the List `Fragment`).

- Press the back button. (no problem here, because I handle this in `onBackPressed()` in `MainActivity`)
- Press the `Toolbar` back arrow (Here is my problem).

When the user presses the toolbar back arrow, I call the following

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

how can I intercept this event in `MainActivity`? 
(There are some manipulations I am doing in `MainActivity` when the List `Fragment` is visible to the user.

Comment: It require to Overwrite  `onOptionsItemSelected` method to intercept the event of toolbar back arrow . You can find full answer in [how to override action bar back button in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437745/how-to-override-action-bar-back-button-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put this code

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I used the following in my DetailsFragment
    
   `@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
        }
        return true;
    }`

Comment: it's okay now, but this applies only to top back arrow