# Passing The Proper Information To Previous Activity When Back Button Pressed

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, android-studio, back-button

I am using the following code to implement the back button in the toolbar:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_series);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar( toolbar );
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(SeriesActivity.this, BowlerActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });
```

My problem is when the .setNavigationOnClickListener registers the click it goes back to the previous activity minus the proper Bowlers.  When I go to the Series Activity I am passing the leagueId and the bowlerId to it.  When I go back to the BowlerActivity I am not passing anything back so I get the following:

[image][image][image]

Bowlers B1 and B2 belong to a different League.

I have gone through several different threads like this one [how to override action bar back button in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437745/how-to-override-action-bar-back-button-in-android) and I have tried several of the different suggestions in them.  None of them worked for me.

How do I pass the leagueId and the bowlerId back to the BowlerActivity so that when it starts up I am filtering the proper Bowler from the database to display in the listview.

Do I even need to pass these values back?  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Comment: where are you getting the bowlers? a server? locally?

Comment: I am getting them from a local SQLite database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your SeriesActivity call the BowlerActivity using  startActivityForResult() method

For example:

```
Intent i = new Intent(SeriesActivity.this, BowlerActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

In your BowlerActivity set the data which you want to return back to SeriesActivity.
If you don't want to return back, don't set any.

```
For example: In BowlerActivity if you want to send back data:

Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();

If you don't want to return data:

Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
finish();
```

Now in your SeriesActivity class write following code for the onActivityResult() method.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Write your code if there's no result
        }
    }
}
```

Source => https://stackoverflow.com/a/10407371/9956766

Comment: With a little modification to the code, using the link you provided above, I was able to get this resolved.  Thanks for your assistance!